# SQL Count multiple Columns Having Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to find duplicate records in columns `[MFG #]`, `[CM HT]`, `[CM WT]`, and `CBM`, while still seeing a few other columns named `ProdKeywords`(not in this SQL statement), and `DateCode`. However I am stuck with the `GROUP BY` clause. MS Access requires me to put in all the columns that I put in the `SELECT` statement. I have also tried putting in each column in the `HAVING` statement.

```
 SELECT First(tblDat01Prod.[DATE CODE]) AS FirstOfDateCode, tblDat01Prod.[MFG #], tblDat01Prod.[CM HT], tblDat01Prod.[CM WDT], tblDat01Prod.[CM DPT], tblDat01Prod.CBM INTO temp_Delete
 FROM tblDat01Prod
 GROUP BY tblDat01Prod.[MFG #], tblDat01Prod.[CM HT], tblDat01Prod.[CM WDT], tblDat01Prod.[CM DPT], tblDat01Prod.CBM
 HAVING (((Count(*))>1));
```

Duplicate records are in '[MFG #]' '[CM HT]' '[CM WDT]' & '[CM DPT]' and I would also like to have it return each record that is a duplicate along with `ProdKeywords` and `DATE CODE`

I'd imagine the query would look something like this

```
 SELECT tblDat01Prod.[DATE CODE], tblDat01Prod.[MFG #], tblDat01Prod.[CM HT], tblDat01Prod.[CM WDT], tblDat01Prod.[CM DPT], tblDat01Prod.CBM, tblDat01Prod.[ProdKeywords]
 FROM tblDat01Prod
 GROUP BY tblDat01Prod.[MFG #], tblDat01Prod.[CM HT], tblDat01Prod.[CM WDT], tblDat01Prod.[CM DPT], tblDat01Prod.CBM
 HAVING (((Count(*))>1)) -----Except for prodkeywords and DATE CODE;
```

Comment: What error do you get?  Why the extra parens around your `COUNT()`?

Comment: Forget about `INTO temp_Delete` until you get a plain `SELECT` query which returns what you want.  What specifically is wrong with this query? ... `SELECT First(t.[DATE CODE]) AS FirstOfDateCode, t.[MFG #], t.[CM HT], t.[CM WDT], t.[CM DPT], t.CBM FROM tblDat01Prod AS t GROUP BY t.[MFG #], t.[CM HT], t.[CM WDT], t.[CM DPT], t.CBM HAVING Count(*)>1;`

Comment: The query returns only one record out of the duplicates. I want to see each duplicate record with. The only columns that contain the duplicates are `MFG #`, `CM HT`, `CM WDT`, `CM DPT`, `CBM`.....`DATE CODE`, and `ProdKeywords` do not have duplicates....When I try to include `DATE CODE` (without an operator) and `ProdKeywords` in the `SELECT` Statement, SQL is looking to have those statements in the `GROUP BY` Clause.... the error is "Your query does not include the specified expression `DATE CODE` as part of the aggregate function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, this query will show you each combination of *MFG #*, *CM HT*, *CM WDT*, *CM DPT*, and *CBM* which is contained in more than one record ...

```sql
SELECT
    t.[MFG #],
    t.[CM HT],
    t.[CM WDT],
    t.[CM DPT],
    t.CBM
FROM tblDat01Prod AS t
GROUP BY
    t.[MFG #],
    t.[CM HT],
    t.[CM WDT],
    t.[CM DPT],
    t.CBM
HAVING Count(*)>1;
```

If that is correct, and the remaining issue is that you want to see the source records which contain those duplicate values, save that query as *qryDupValues*.  Then create a new query which joins your *tblDat01Prod* table to *qryDupValues*.

```sql
SELECT
    t.[MFG #],
    t.[CM HT],
    t.[CM WDT],
    t.[CM DPT],
    t.CBM,
    t.ProdKeywords,
    t.[DATE CODE]
FROM
    tblDat01Prod AS t
    INNER JOIN qryDupValues AS q
    ON
            t.[MFG #] = q.[MFG #]
        AND t.[CM HT] = q.[CM HT]
        AND t.[CM WDT] = q.[CM WDT]
        AND t.[CM DPT] = q.[CM DPT]
        AND t.CBM = q.[CBM];
```

Alternatively you could use a subquery in place of the separate *qryDupValues* saved query.  And you can do that later if desired.  But I hoped this stacked query approach would be easier to manage initially.

Comment: Thank you! To be clear on what you did, you are using the `INNER JOIN` to fill the values that are duplicates, and then add the unique fields from the `SELECT` statement in the 2nd Query. I am still new at programming, and I appreciate all the help I have found and receive, I hope I can give back knowledge as I get better....

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you just asked.  I would say *qryDupValues* identifies the duplicate values.  Then inner joining *tblDat01Prod* to  *qryDupValues*, "filters" *tblDat01Prod* to display only those rows which match the duplicate values.